# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'sf_sandbox.phpcr_workspaces' doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, configuration, backend

I installed symfony-standard edition.After some struggle with parameters.yml there was progress... the database_driver was set to  pdo_mysqln and the running proceeded however there were 6 occurences of the same error in different php files .and the error was:

Unexpected error talking to the backend: An exception occurred while executing `'SELECT 1 FROM phpcr_workspaces WHERE name = ?' with params ["default"]:`

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'sf_sandbox.phpcr_workspaces' doesn't exist
```

any ideas?

Comment: Post the entity code here so we can help you.

Comment: Also did you make sure that table actually exists in your database?

Comment: phpcr_workspaces is not in  my database; it' probably belongs to configuration (maybe for the sqLite driver).I change the driver to pdo_Mysql and everything crushes when i view the app_dev.php the errors are brought.

Comment: truth is, after ading the table a new error message came requesting a fieldname from the table but i donot know how far can this go...the table, used for internal purposes, might have tenths of fields.So my question rather narrows to if there are scripts in the standard edition or if you can turn off the feature the table provides or an estimate of how many tables/columns will there appear.Someone must know something

Comment: Using ur terminal, run: php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force     this will update ur database to match ur entities

Answer (score 0):

You must update your database with the current schema information, which includes creating the tables in the database:

```
# show the SQL commands to be applied (if you want to execute them yourself)
app/console doctrine:schema:update --force --dump-sql

# have Symfony apply the SQL commands
app/console doctrine:schema:update --force --complete
```